# Error 426 Failure reading network stream, 'ftp_put' uploads files incompletely, works fine when restarting the server

Tags: ftp

Having an issue with ftp_put, 'ftp_put' returns false and files are only transferred incompletely. The error returned is 426 Failure reading network stream. Restart of the server is fixing the issue for 2 or 3 days. Also When changing the destination folder to another server all files are uploaded without any problem.

With another server, I am able to transfer the same file to same destination. Had the issue with this server too, a restart of this server fixed the error(temporarily). So now the issue is with the other server.

Any possible chances for resource locks which automatically fixed while restarting the server. What are the main logs to check for this issue? Also where should I check to know if some resource locking happens? Or something else...

Destination server is using vsftpd and the source is having proftpd sever. Is there any changes needed in the configuration source or detination servers? What could be the reason for failure of these file uploads until restart of the source server and 426 network streaming error?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:The issue was fixed in the month of June.

The problem was with the write over disk in the host server. The write over disk was very slow. Also the corresponding logs were written with high lag. A high lag in sending mails helped in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this error with my vsftp server.  The problem turned out to be a false positive from the firewall's virus checker.  Indicators of this problem are:
* affects only certain files (ie, in a multi-file upload, some files get through and other files fail repeatably)
* when an upload fails, part of the file is written to the destination
* the failure always occurs after the same number of bytes have been written (for a given file)

If you aren't able to temporarily disable the firewall's virus scanner, and you are certain that the file is virus-free, a workaround is to upload the file as a password-protected .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it had nothing to do with slow disk writes, network lag, firewall, etc. I just didn't notice the free space on my `vsftp server`. The disk was full so I increased the `disk quota` and everything's working!